# python3 zip result used twice

Tags: list, python-3.x, iterator

I am using twice the result of `zip` on two lists in two distinct `for` loops in Python 3. What's the most pythonic way of writing this ?

1. Using zip() twice

   ```
   for j in range(123) :
       for x,y in zip(list1,list2) :
           doSomething()
   ....
   for x,y in zip(list1,list2) :
       doSomethingElse()
   ```
2. Storing the result of zip as a list

   ```
   z=list(zip(list1,list2))
   for j in range(123) :
       for x,y in z :
           doSomething()
   for x,y in z :
       doSomethingElse()
   ```

I would really appreciate to hear about the internals of Python in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the first method:

```
for j in range(123) :
    for x,y in zip(list1,list2) :
        doSomething()
....
for x,y in zip(list1,list2) :
    doSomethingElse()
```

In Python 3, the zip method does not create a new list of pairs from your existing lists. It simply creates an iterator that references the input lists for each iteration. It's very efficient compared to the Python 2 way which created an entirely new list.

For this reason you can use `zip` command multiple times, as I believe this makes the code easier to read and more succinct (no instantiation of a new list reference at the top of the code, in general you want to avoid create named references if you can avoid it since it gives you one more reference name you need to remember - this is also part of the reason anonymous functions are more appealing).

Comment: This is Python 3, so `izip` doesn't exist. `zip` does that job.

Comment: I thought about using `itertools.tee` to copy the iterator but the documentation says : In general, if one iterator uses most or all of the data before another iterator starts, it is faster to use list() instead of tee().

Comment: Updated my answer for Python 3. Thanks @user2357112